# File permissions for openssl created files for https web server (lighttpd)

Tags: permissions, https, openssl, lighttpd

I've created the following files for my lighttpd webserver for https connections:

```
$ ls -al /etc/lighttpd/ssl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Oct 21 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Oct 20 16:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 http  http  1663 Oct 20 15:49 server.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1062 Oct 20 15:48 server.csr
-rw------- 1 root  root  1704 Oct 20 15:48 server.key
-rw-r----- 1 alarm http  3367 Oct 20 16:02 server.pem
-rw------- 1 root  root  1751 Oct 20 15:48 rootCA.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1330 Oct 20 15:48 rootCA.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    41 Oct 20 15:49 rootCA.srl
```

where `server.*` are my obvious webserver files and `rootCA.*` files are my certificate authority (CA) files that I used to create my self signing certificate (https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/). In order for me to have lighttpd use my certificate (crt), I needed to create my pem formatted file but doing:

`sudo cat server.crt server.key > server.pem` to make a pem formatted file. I installed my rootCA.pem file into Chrome (So it would recognize the CA and not complain about the website 'not being secure').

So my questions are

1. are my file permissions OK from a security perspective or should I change owner/group and file permissions to be something else?
2. What about the /etc/lighttpd/ssl directory permissions?
3. Where I had to do the `sudo cat server.crt server.key > server.pem` command above by adding my `server.key` to the pem file, doesn't this expose my private key by making that `server.pem` file readable by http?

My server.pem has to be readable by my lighttpd server as the user that runs lighttpd is 'http'.

Answer (score 0):

This may not have received any responses yet because it's a difficult problem, and there's no single correct answer.

Key access for servers comes down to a trade-off between attended and unattended startup. You can require interaction with an administrator (e.g. encrypt the private key file and enter the passphrase manually at startup); that protects the key at rest (on disk) from exposure, but prevents unattended startup. Or you can make the key-at-rest available to the server, allowing unattended startup, but that potentially exposes it to attackers.

So the key-at-rest hygiene has to reflect your threat model. Is it worth the cost (time, inconvenience, delay in startup) to require interaction? Or is the risk of key disclosure (probability of it happening times cost to you) low enough that you can allow unattended startup?

Assuming you continue to keep the server's private key available for unattended startup (i.e. readable by the server with no administrator interaction), here are some considerations:

1. Get the root key off there. CA keys should not be kept on systems exposed to the outside world. In this case it's your own CA, not a big public one, but this is basic PKIX key hygiene.
2. There's probably no additional exposure from having the server key present in two forms, but there's no advantage to it either. Get rid of server.key.
3. The directory might as well be owned by root.http and set to 750 (root writable, http-group readable, no world permissions). The most likely attack vectors are through the HTTP server, but there are others; might as well discourage some of them by blocking world read/traverse.

Regarding your final question: I've never used lighttpd, but some servers support a keying process where the server reads the key at startup and then drops permissions in a way that prevents it from reading it subsequently. For example, the server may start as root (as it must, on UNIX/Linux, if it wants to bind to ports 80 and 443), reads the key file then, and then does a setuid to http (or whatever). Others might have a provision for reading the key from a pipe or similar.

It may also be possible with lighttpd to have it read the key from a temporary copy which the startup procedure deletes after the server starts.

The first line of defense, though, would be to make sure the directory containing the key file is not accessible through any of the webroots, and doing your best to avoid path-traversal vulnerabilities in whatever the server is serving. And locking down the OS in general.

I like Ivan Ristić's *Bulletproof SSL and TLS* book, available from feistyduck.com, for advice in using SSL/TLS in general and with HTTPS in particular. For web servers, he discusses Apache primarily, but much of the material is broadly applicable.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

root:root, chmod 400. And ideally your Root CA files should not be
hosted on your web server, otherwise a server compromise also
compromises your root authority.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_ssl
Permissions
Be careful to keep your .pem file private! Lighttpd reads all pemfiles
at startup, before dropping privileges. It is therefore best to make
the pem file owned by root and readable by root only:
$ chown root:root /etc/lighttpd/ssl/example.org.pem
$ chmod 400 /etc/lighttpd/ssl/example.org.pem